# Google App Scripts - How to clear multiple cells' content based on another cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to check a column's values for the words "No Show" and if a cell has that value I need it to delete some cells on the same row so for example if column I5 has "No Show" as its value I need to clear cells B5,C5,D5,F5,G5. I tried to write something but its not working and im relatively new to this. Thanks for the help

Comment: That worked perfectly , Thank you so much.
Could I ask you to explain this part?

flatMap(r => {
      const row = r.getRow();
      return ["B", "C", "D", "F", "G"].map(e => e + row);
    });
  if (ranges.length > 0) sheet.getRangeList(ranges).clearContent();
}

Comment: By the way, when you comment, can you comment it to my answer? By this, I can notice when I logged in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to clear the cell values of the columns "B", "C", "D", "F" and "G", when the value of column "I" is `No Show` for each row.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to propose to use TextFinder and the method of `clearContent()` of Class RangeList. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set the sheet name you want to use, and run the function `myFunction` at the script editor.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const ranges = sheet
    .getRange("I1:I" + sheet.getLastRow())
    .createTextFinder("No Show")
    .matchCase(true)
    .findAll()
    .flatMap(r => {
      const row = r.getRow();
      return ["B", "C", "D", "F", "G"].map(e => e + row);
    });
  if (ranges.length > 0) sheet.getRangeList(ranges).clearContent();
}
```

- When this script is run, the cell values of columns "B", "C", "D", "F" and "G" are cleared, when the value of column "I" is `No Show` for each row.
- About the search value of `No Show`, when you want to check `No Show`, `no show` and so on, please remove `.matchCase(true)`.

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [clearContent() of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#clearContent())